# create table with 2 column with different conditions SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with this format:

```
Id_command, date_creat
01  01-01-2020
02 01-01-2021
03 01-11-2020
..
```

I would like to extract from a table a new table where the first table contain all the id_command where date_creat > 01-01-2020 and a second column where date_creat > 01-01-2021.

The expected result :

```
Id_command (date_creat > 01-01-2020) , id command(date_creat < 31-12-2020)
01                                         02
03
```

I got the idea to crate two differnt table, then outer_join, but i am not sure if we can do this with a simpler manner
Thanks

Comment: Add some more sample table data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: sql with Oracle, thanks

Comment: @jarlh i just update my post with and expect result exmaple , thanks

Answer (score 0):

First select the relevant rows from the table and add a *row number*

```
select Id_command,
row_number() over (order by Id_command) as rn
from tab
where date_creat > DATE'2020-01-01'

ID_COMMAND         RN
---------- ----------
         2          1
         3          2
```

Make the same for the second conditions.

Finally use those two subqueries and *full outer join* them using the row number.

```
with a as(
select Id_command,
row_number() over (order by Id_command) as rn
from tab
where date_creat > DATE'2020-01-01'
),  b as (
select Id_command,
row_number() over (order by Id_command) as rn
from tab
where date_creat <= DATE'2020-01-01')
select a.Id_command, b.Id_command
from a
full outer join b 
on a.rn = b.rn
order by 1,2

ID_COMMAND ID_COMMAND
---------- ----------
         2          1
         3
```